# Java SwingWorker passing arguments and returning

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I'd like to pass in `String s, ArrayList<String> als` and return 
`ArrayList<String> als`

Run.java

```
class Run extends SwingWorker<String, Void>
{
    private ArrayList<String> als;
    private String s;


    public Run(String s, ArrayList<String> als) {
       this.s = s;
       this.als = als;
    }

    public String doInBackground()
    {
        return AnotherClass.doSomething(s, als);
    }

    public void done()
    {
        try 
        { 
        } 
        catch (Exception ignore) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

AnotherClass.java

```
public class AnotherClass{
    public static String doSomething(String ipRange, ArrayList<String> nmapPorts) {
        //do some stuff with the strings
        try{
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("someexe", "flag", cmds,
            "&cd");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process pr = builder.start();
            //do some stuff with the stream.
            return aString;
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the next line of the stack trace. It ends with the name of the file, and the line in this file, where the error is.

Comment: I added it to the description.

Comment: Now read the message of the exception. And read the signature and javadoc of the execute() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute%28%29. It doesn't have any argument.

Comment: So how do I pass this whole thing any arguments? I have ClassA, I want it to call this method in ClassB. ClassB takes too long so I want it to do it in it's own thread. But ClassB need 2 parameters from ClassA. So I thought to create this Class as a middleman that can spin off the thread.

Comment: Your own code shows that you have a constructor of the Run class which takes these two arguments. Call your constructor. (And remove the one without argument, which should never be called, since it would make the SwingWorker fail)

Comment: @JBNizet: why not make your comments into an answer since it is the obvious and only solution to the original question?

Comment: Also, your SwingWorker generic parameters -- `SwingWorker<ArrayList<String>, Void>` -- imply that the `doInBackground()` method will return an array of String, but it appears to return only a String: -- `public String doInBackground()` -- You should be getting a compilation error for this, are you?

Comment: wow duh...thanks. this code runs but im not able to continue interacting with the application. So, it doesn't seam to be threading correctly. Any, ideas?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: feel free to do it. I wanted to guide the OP and teach him to read the error message, the stack trace and the javadoc rather than give him a ready-made solution.

Comment: @user126: how are you calling the SwingWorker? Are you using the `execute()` method correctly now? I have a feeling that there are too many unknowns for us to know why your application is becoming unresponsive now.

Comment: @JB - I did read the problem. I needed help to get to the answer. Hovercraft is right

Comment: @user126: no, JB is guiding you towards a better understanding or the error messages, and in doing this, he is correct and helping you the best way possible. It's the old give a man a fish vs. teach a man to fish thing.

Comment: Anyway...this doesn't seam to be threading even though its executing. Any ideas?

Comment: @user126: I don't think that the cause for your possible threading problem can be id'd based on the information posted so far. Consider giving more information -- how much? enough so that we can answer the question, but not so much as to drown us in a lot of unrelated code. If you're *still* without a solution, then consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable runnable program that demonstrates the problem and has no extraneous code unrelated to the problem. It will take a bit of work to do this, but sometime is necessary for us to solve this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added the jist of what AnotherClass does. Is this enough information?

Comment: @user126: no, it's not enough for me except to worry me that you may be ignoring some very important exceptions. Why not put something in those catch blocks. And an unrelated question is -- how are you running your SwingWorker instance now?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i left out lots to keep the code lean.  `someString = package.Run.Run(anotherString, arrList);`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Run is a class, and you appear to be calling its constructor as if it were a method. If you don't show real code that you've double checked, you're just wasting your time and ours.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Wow that was my main problem. I had a class and a method named too closely alike. Thank you.

Comment: Yow.  Don't do that. Anyway, the method to call is `execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have initialized your class members in constructor you can always use global variables in SwingWorker.

```
class Run extends SwingWorker<List<String>, Void, Void>
{
private ArrayList<String> als;
private String s;


public Run(String s, ArrayList<String> als) {
   this.s = s;
   this.als = als;
}

public String doInBackground()
{
    //this is right way to do it and you are correct here.
    //Following called method must return ArrayList<String> 
    return AnotherClass.doSomething(s, als);
}

public void done()
{
    ArrayList<String> retList = null;
    try 
    { 
         //When doInBackground finishes done method is called and to get data from doInBackground it uses following method
         retList = get();
         als = retList;
    } 
    catch (Exception ignore) 
    {
    }
}
```

}